# How to make "Live chart" in excel with scrollbar

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I added a scroll bar form control to Sheet 1.  Its value goes to cell A1.
When I move the slider on the control, the value in A1 changes "live"  i.e. as I move the slider.

Then I added some fixed numbers in A2 and A3 and a pie chart which references A1:A3.  The chart shows the relative proportions of A1:A3, but:

**It does not update as the numbers change, only upon mouse release.**

Initially I thought that only A1 was being recalc, but adding a dependent calculation clearly shows that subsequent calc also are evaluated.

I tried to start writing a macro to force the recalculation of the spreadsheet, but:

1) the Worksheet_Change() event does **NOT** get called, even on mouse release!

2) I have not been able to find a way to force the graph to refresh i.e.

*There does not seem to be any way to force an object to refresh in Excel*

I expected the chart to change upon data change, but there appears to be some deeper logic in Excel which is not described anywhere for how refresh actually works.

I can totally see why (performance) this would have been coded this way, but I can't seem to understand how they did it, or how to make it not do it that way when we want something else to happen.

Comment: Please post your code.  It is hard to help if we can't see what you have done.

Comment: Works for me if I use an ActiveX scrollbar

Comment: Hmmm.  Thanks!  ActiveX seems to work differently than Form controls.  Weird.  I think the point of the question is still valid since ActiveX doesn't work on a mac....  I would love to see if there is anyone out there that knows how the two really behave.